# Acumatica - Access rights issue with Production Screens

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We recently upgraded from 2019R1 to 2020R2 (Build 20.208.0031) and we observed that permissions got reset only in all production screens, can someone please help me out how to restore them back.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of the old Acumatica instance you could try adding the access rights to a customization project and publishing them on the site.

**Please first test this on a UAT site or locally as I have never tried doing it between versions**

[image]